# Checkboxes, como não selecionar a desabilitada

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

Tenho uma lista de checkboxes e tenho uma função que faz o prop e já(esta funcionando) marca todas, e gostaria de saber como q eu faço para selecionar todas menos a desabilitada.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cliente_[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="cliente_[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="cliente_[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="cliente_[]" disabled value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="cliente_[]" value="5">
```

```
<script>
  $("#marcar").click(function() {
    $("input[name^='cliente_']").prop('checked',true);
    return false;
  });

  $("#desmarcar").click(function() {
    $("input[name^='cliente_']").prop('checked',false);
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adicione o seletor `:not(:disabled)`:

```
$("input[name^='cliente_']:not(:disabled)").prop('checked',true);
```

Exemplo:

```js
$("#marcar").click(function() {
    $("input[name^='cliente_']:not(:disabled)").prop('checked',true);
    return false;
});

$("#desmarcar").click(function() {
    $("input[name^='cliente_']").prop('checked',false);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="cliente_[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="cliente_[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="cliente_[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="cliente_[]" disabled value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="cliente_[]" value="5">
<br>
<button id="marcar">Marcar</button>
<button id="desmarcar">Desmarcar</button>
```

O `:not` significa que será excluído da seleção o que estiver dentro dos parênteses, ou seja, o `:disabled`, que é o seletor dos elementos que possuem o atributo `disabled`.

Comment: ai sabe eim...top funcionou perfeitamente!!!!! abraços obrigado.

Comment: De nada. Por favor marque a resposta como respondida. Obg